# AngularJS how to add data-image attribute to option

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I want to add custom data attribute to option tag.

For example:

```
<select>
    <option data-image="url 1">Val 1</option>
    <option data-image="url 2">Val 2</option>
    <option data-image=" ... "> ... </option>
    <option data-image="url N">Val N</option>
<select>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is impossible with the `select` directive (see the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)). But you can easily make what you want with `ngRepeat` ([see the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)):

```
<select ng-model="choice">
    <option ng-repeat="item in itemsList" data-image="{{item.url}}">{{item.label}}</option>
</select>
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/a61pv1jr/)</kbd>

Comment: Seems ng-change doesn't fire using this approach.

Comment: This will cause you all kinds of headaches. I spent all day debugging an issue where I could change the value of the model once from the controller -- but only once. Super weird.

Comment: @Blackhole Weird, I had a Plunker setup demonstrating the broken behaviour and everything (http://plnkr.co/edit/myWzlE), now it's working. If you do a trivial edit to the answer I can de-downvote it — apologies!

Comment: @aendrew Done. No need to apologize, it's a pleasure to see a critical reviewer :) !

Answer (score 1):

have done a little modification to @Blackhole's answer.
Try this code pen:

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/NomeshD/pen/jJoYJd)

```
function loadCountryFlagCtrl($scope) {

   $scope.countries = [
    {
      country_id: "SL", 
      name:"Sri Lanka",      flag:"http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gosquared/flag/24/Sri-Lanka-flat-icon.png"
    },{
      country_id: "IND", 
      name:"India",      flag:"http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gosquared/flag/24/Andorra-flat-icon.png"
    }
  ];

}
```

And the **HTML**:

```
<div ng-controller="loadCountryFlagCtrl">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="header">
          <form action="">


             <div class="select_list" ng-class='{active:active}' ng-click="active=!active">
    <span ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+countries.country_selected.flag+')'}">{{countries.country_selected.name}}</span>
    <ul class="options">
        <li class="select_list_option" ng-repeat="country in countries" ng-click="countries.country_selected=country" ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+country.flag+')'}">{{country.name}}</li>
        </ul>
</div>
          <br/>
             <div>selected country:{{countries.country_selected.name}}</div>
           </form>


        </div>

    </div>
```

and the **CSS**:

```
.select_list{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 21px;
    line-height: 21px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 250px;
}
.select_list:after{
    content:"▼";
    position:absolute;
    right:3px;
    color:#b3b3b3;
}
.select_list > .options{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:-1px;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #666;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.select_list.active > .options{
    display:block;
}

.select_list > span, .select_list > .options li {
    background-position: 5px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;
    list-style:none;
}

.select_list > .options li:hover {
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

Hope this will be helpful for other programmers :)